# "Each of them is" "Each of them are"

Tags: grammar

I am having difficulty understanding which is correct as each seems to be singular and them seems to be plural.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Each of them is..."

The subject of such a sentence is *each*, which is a singular noun. The phrase *of them* modifies each, but it doesn't turn it into a plural noun. It just specifies a group which the subject is a part of.